# Doctrine multiples entity managers datatable creation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, entitymanager

I set up 2 `EntityManager` in my project (default, em2). No error seemed to pop up, but although I specified a folder to split up entities related to each `EntityManager`, **Doctrine keeps creating tables related to em2 in default database** (currently using `doctrine:schema:update` as in heavy development time). What am I missing? I also tried to make the command using the `--em` option, but it keeps having the same unwanted behavior.

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                # configure these for your database server
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
            em2:
                # configure these for your database server
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
                schema_filter: ~^(?!m_sqlviewstate)~

                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_EM2_URL)%'
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                #                auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                auto_mapping: false
                mappings:
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: App
            em2:
                connection: em2
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                mappings:
                    Em2:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Em2'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Em2'
                        alias: Em2
```

**EDIT** : I tried to move away em2 entities from `Entity` folder. This seemed to work regarding tables generation, i.e. I don't have em2 entities generated table in default database anymore.

However, I get now an error regarding bundle entities.

> The class 'App\Entity\Shop\User' was not found in the chain configured namespaces Lch\MenuBundle\Entity

AFAIK, this seems to come from the fact that I would need to **manually register each and every bundle dir/namespace on the default `EntityManager`**.
I don't get why, because the default is marked as `auto_mapping` :

Below the modified part for `orm` :

```
    orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            auto_mapping: true
        em2:
            connection: em2
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            mappings:
                Em2:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Em2Entity'
                    prefix: 'App\Em2Entity'
                    alias: Em2
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Doctrine in Symfony loads all mapping it can grab in default locations (eg. `src/Entity`). You need to turn this off.

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_mapping: false
```

> Doctrine's auto_mapping feature loads annotation configuration from the Entity/ directory of each bundle and looks for other formats (e.g. YAML, XML) in the Resources/config/doctrine directory.

https://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#custom-mapping-entities-in-a-bundle

And also your `Entity/Em2` is subfolder of `Entity` which means first `EntityManager` will be loading all entities in all subfolders. Move it to separate path.

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        em2:
            mappings:
                Em2:
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/EntityEm2'
```

Comment: I added the `auto_mapping: false` on the default entity manager, and it's not working. I will try to get the second entity manager classes out of `src/Entity` folder.

Comment: don't add it on manager, add it on the same key i posted, directly under `orm`

Comment: and i just noticed your `Em2` entities are under subfolder of `Entity`, add them to separate path, eg. `src/Entity2`

Comment: This is not possible, as soon as you specify multiple entity managers, all the keys usually found under orm migrate under each entity manager in order to allow specific configuration to each. Keeping keys here throw an exception. Furthermore it seems [to be discouraged to have more than one entity manager with `auto_mapping` to true](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/60#issuecomment-5218727).

Comment: Yes, as I stated one message above, I moved them from the `Entity` folder and it seems to work. My original interrogation was linked to the fact that I would have initially preferred to keep entities in the same place.